Range of square root operator.
If A is a positive operator then is it true $R(A^{1/2})$ is the subset of closure of $R(A)$(Range of A)?

Welcome to MathSE! Please see how to ask a good question. It’s better to show your attempt in the post. What progress did you achieve? Where were you “stuck”?
